Individual via tenting control on KiCad 8
I am using KiCad 8 and trying to figure out how can I control tenting on individual vias. I want to keep most of my vias (specially stitching vias) tented, but I want some vias placed on a thermal pad of buck converter to be un-tended. How can I do this without creating a separate footprint?
I want the vias in the screenshot un-tented to release heat in the air.


What I do in such cases is placing graphical circles in the F.Mask and B.Mask layers to expose individual vias as shown below. The advantage is that you can opt to untent only one side if necessary.
If you wish to expose an entire array of vias, you could also draw rectangles or other polygons into the mask layers.

After production:

